# Match exactly 2x == to another 2x ==

Tags: regex, regex-group

How do you exactly match 2 '=='  to another '==', taking everything inside of it EXCEPT for the 2x == tags?

For example I have the following text where I need to get everything between the two '==' brackets. Below I would want to get A and E (I don't mind whitespace between A).

`== A ==
gremjkgmek
=== B === 
evev3tt3wtegrget
==== C ==== 
regikegerg
=== D === 
rekgmer
== E == 
emrgmegm`

You can just paste the above on https://regexr.com/

I was using the following regular expression:

```
==([^=]+?)==*
```

but with this I'm obviously matching everything (A, B, C, D, E) since it doesn't ignore whenever it encounters three or four '=' tokens. So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe [`(?<!=)==([^=]+)==(?!=)`](https://regex101.com/r/a3sdEe/1) will do?

Comment: ...so what exactly was your problem? The site rules say that a question "must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error", so I'd suggest you write what you did, what happened and what you expected to happen instead. Also, with regular expressions, there are a few dialects, so it might be worth mentioning which one you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much, (?<!=)==([^=]+)==(?!=) indeed worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ^ and $:

```
^ ... matches the beginning of the string
$ ... matches the end of the string
```

Here is your solution:

```
^==([^=]+?)==$
```

**Edit**:
In your example were spaces at the end of some lines (maybe just a copy/past issue through the webpage?), in this case you might want to use this (to also check on white spaces at the end):

```
^==([^=]+?)==\s*$
```

Keep in mind, that you need to enable the multi line flag.
https://regexr.com/3mdi3